# Is this impossible to install XP using BootCamp on Lion?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I want to install XP with bootcamp on my Mac running Lion. The only choice that it gives me is to install Win7. Is there a way to install XP on Lion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Bootcamp: You can bypass it by putting in a Windows7 disk and format the drive for the Windows installation.
2. After that you just restart, press alt to bring up the boot menu and put in your Windows XP CD to install.

One way that should work aswell(havent tested) is if you just create a new empty FAT-partition and then go to step 2.